# Android: using a Singleton to load data from the network

Tags: android, singleton, rx-android

So here is a very standard task in Android: load data from the server and display it on the screen. One of the biggest problems is, of course, handling configuration changes. For example, when loading is started and device is rotated, the loading must not be started again and loading progress must still be shown.

Now, there is a ridiculous number of ways people approach this basic problem. Let's say, we use the Model-View-Presenter pattern. A lot of solutions revolve around saving Presenter, entirely or partially (in the View's bundle, in a Singleton or any other way), to not lose data on rotation. Others involve Retained Fragments and AsyncTasks. And I quite rarely encounter a solution that uses a Singleton to perform loading data! Why is that?

Here's the way I think it can be easily done. We make Presenters "light" and not perform any state saving, and handle data loading in a Repository that is a Singleton. When device is rotated, the newly created Presenter can just get current loading status from the Repository, update its View accordingly and, if data is loading, resubscribe to the Repository (via callbacks or RxJava Observable) to get notified when data is loaded. As for the Repository, it can easily load data in the background with the help of RxAndroid. So, isn't it easier to handle all data loading business in one place and not worry about activity's lifecycle?

This way we basically skip the whole configuration change problem. There are only a couple of things I see that must be handled carefully:

- Activity leaks in the Singleton. To prevent this we just have to unsubscribe  Presenter from the Repository when its View gets destroyed.
- Testing, as it is harder to test a Singleton. But this is not an issue if we use Dagger - in this case we can test out Repository like any other class.

So my question is this: why is this approach (performing data loading in a Singleton) is not a common solution? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I seriously recommend you read up on a library specific for the purpose of network requests, rather then trying to reinvent the wheel and having to deal with all the pitfalls which might arise.

Recently I've been trying out RoboSpice. If you read up on their page below, you'll see that it "executes network requests asynchronously (in a background AndroidService)", precisely to avoid memory leaks.

I say, give it a try! Lots of projects in my workplace make use of RoboSpice and they all work pretty well.

https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer and, in a real project, is probably the correct one. RoboSpice does make it very easy to solve the device rotation problem. But I'm still curious - is it bad to use a Singleton to make network (or any other, for that matter) long-running calls, even if we carefully avoid memory leaks?

Comment: I can't really tell you for sure. There are many articles around the web explaining why it's bad to use singletons in android. IMO, as long as you don't store references to Context or View objects in them, it should be ok.